# How to check whether a specific row exists in a JDatabase table?

Tags: mysql, jdatabase

What would be the best way to check whether a specific row exists already in a JDatabase table?

Instead of INSERT INTO Command, I need to execute a UPDATE command if the row already exists.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question details, "Instead of INSERT INTO Command, I need to execute a UPDATE command if the row already exists" ?

Comment: Truth is, you don't need to check first.  Just send the UPDATE query.  If there isn't a qualifying row(s), there will be no affected rows.  Is that satisfactory?

Comment: What I am asking is: do you really need to isolate each possible outcome or only if an update was successful?https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22985/12352

Comment: I needed them to be isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets say you would like to update the username `Saibbyweb` in the `#__users` table to something like `Saibbyweb123`.

You're going to need to perform a `select` query first to see if the row already exists:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('username'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__users'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('username') . ' = '. $db->quote('Saibbyweb'));
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadResult();
```

The `$result` will now either contain the username, or be `null`.

So you can now run your `update` query if the result does is not `null`:

```
if ($result !== null)
{
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->clear();

    $fields     = array($db->quoteName('username') . ' = ' . $db->quote('Saibbyweb123'));
    $conditions = array($db->quoteName('username') . ' = ' . $db->quote($result));

    $query->update($db->quoteName('#__users'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should propagate JTable for this case ; )
`if(JTable->load([$key => $value]))` `return true` if record exists and `false` if record not exists then you can use `->store` to insert / update record.

Comment: @Lanah - That is under the assumption that this is for a component ;) Seeing as nothing was mentioned, I just used a simple database query

Comment: true, but he might be using some kind of core tables : ) and if not he should create JTable in module / plugin :)