# How can I translate SQL code into something that Joomla will take?

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the same case discussed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709043/mysql-update-column-with-value-from-another-table, that is, I need to copy the value of a column from tableA to tableB based on a common column in each table.

I have used the suggested code inside of PHPMyAdmin, and it works perfectly:

```
UPDATE TableB 
SET TableB.value = (
    SELECT TableA.value 
    FROM TableA
    WHERE TableA.name = TableB.name
);
```

My problem is that I have been unable to translate this into something that I can use inside of my `mod_xxx.php` file. On the same Stack Overflow page, there is a suggested code that uses `mysql_query` and supposedly works, but Joomla doesn´t accept it. I know that any code has to be translated to Joomla's coding standards but I have spent three complete days trying it with no success.

I have tried the following code unsuccessfully:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query ->UPDATE ('#__gruposlocales')
       ->SET ('#__gruposlocales.name') =
             (SELECT ('#__community_groups.name')
              FROM ('#__community_groups')
              WHERE ('#__community_groups.ownerid = #__gruposlocales.id'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->execute();
```

As you may guess, I am not knowledgeable on PHP coding, so I am in serious need of your help, please. My question is how can I translate the upper code into something that Joomla will take?

Comment: Are you trying to execute it as a raw sql query or build it using the query builder? You should be able to run it like this if you know that it works in phpmyadmin $db->setQuery($your_sql); $result = $db->execute();

Comment: Thank you, James. I have tried the following code unsuccessfully:  
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query ->UPDATE ('#__gruposlocales') ->SET ('#__gruposlocales.name') = (SELECT  ('#__community_groups.name') FROM ('#__community_groups') WHERE ('#__community_groups.ownerid = #__gruposlocales.id'));
$db->setQuery($query); $result = $db->execute();

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$sql = "UPDATE TableB SET TableB.value = (SELECT TableA.value FROM TableA WHERE TableA.name = TableB.name);
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: The common column is id/ownerid, not name. And since this problem can be confusing, I'll try to clarify it a little further.
TableB = josok_gruposlocales ;  colum to update= name
Table A= josok_community_groups ; colum to be copied= name
Primary key= id  ;  foreign key= ownerid
https://lab.latinface.com/images/photos/567/1/Problem-TableA&B.jpg
TableB was updated from inside phpmyAdmin using the upper code that uses #__tablenames.
But when I try to translate it into terms of $query and #__tablaname to be used inside of the mod_module.php I am creating, the update does not happen.

Comment: mr octopus meant to write: "$db->setQuery($sql); " If you have a query that works in phpmyadmin then you can assign the raw query to $sql and it should work.

Comment: @jamesgarrett Correct! Sorry the query was updated.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong?
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$sql = "UPDATE josok_gruposlocales
SET josok_gruposlocales.name = (
    SELECT josok_community_groups.name 
    FROM josok_community_groups
    WHERE josok_community_groups.ownerid = josok_gruposlocales.id
)";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$db->execute();

Comment: @pablo I have tested your code with table prefix placeholder (#__), worked for me. You could create 2 simple tables with column ID and VALUE. Then add one entry to each table with different values. Test your SQL code with those 2 tables. You could also check var_dump($db->execute()); var_dump((string)$db->getQuery());

Comment: @Dennis, James, itoctopus, thank you. The code is working today, with a long response from my server though; long enough to think it still was not working. In the meantime, my module exhibited some weird behavior like showing part of some code. But, I know now that the code is good!

Comment: I know what happened. This is surely a beginner's mistake but telling about it could be useful for somebody else. The code is not executed as I save my mod_module.php file but when a user logs in and the mod_module is loaded. Thanks again and I am sorry for my lack of expertise.

Comment: @PabloCastelo If this answer helped you to resolve your issue, perhaps you'd like to award this answer the green tick so that this page is deemed resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla should be able to understand this... You must let Joomla's query building functions render the "child query"/subquery before placing it inside of the "parent query"/main query.

Here are some other answers of mine that may prove helpful while writing/testing your own query:

- [Method for creating a subquery using JDatabase](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24201/12352)
- [Correct ways to verify update query is successful under conditions](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22985/12352)

Code: (untested)

```
$subquery = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select("cg.name")
    ->from("#__community_groups AS cg")
    ->where("cg.ownerid = gl.id");

$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->update("#__gruposlocales AS gl")
    ->set("gl.name = ({$subquery})");

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

I am deliberately omitting all quoting techniques in my answer because they are unnecessary fir stability/security in this snippet and would only serve to make the snippet more difficult to read.

As for discussions on how/when/why to quote query entities, how to view the rendered query with `dump()`, how to write a `try{}catch{}` block to aid in debugging, and how to check for affected rows -- please see my other [mysql-tagged answers](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12352%20%5Bmysql%5D%20is%3Aanswer) in this community.